# Many table sorting with first td

Tags: jquery, sorting, html-table

I have many tables:

```
<table id="342">
  <tr>
     <td>342</td>
     <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="533">
  <tr>
     <td>533</td>
     <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="156">
  <tr>
     <td>156</td>
     <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Can I sort these tables with first td jquery from 1 to ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
<table id="342">
  <tr>
     <td>342</td>
     <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="533">
  <tr>
     <td>533</td>
     <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="156">
  <tr>
     <td>156</td>
     <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var tables = $('table');

tables.sort(function(a, b) {
    return parseInt($('tr td:first', a).html()) > parseInt($('tr td:first', b).html())
});
$('div#test').empty().append(tables);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pp9JB/1/)**

Comment: thanks dear. but this script changes other tables that i don't want to change. do you have any idea?

Comment: @chalist you can assign a class to those tables you wanted to sort and then isstead of using `var tables = $(table)` use `var tables = $(table.CLASS_NANE)`.